# Play one sound after another with SDL_mixer?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-mixer

I have 4 sounds. When sound 1 finishes, I need to automatically play sound 2; when sound 2 finishes, automatically play sound 3; when sound 3 finishes, play sound 4.... I'm using SDL Mixer 2.0, no SDL Sound... is there a way to do this?

```
int main() {
    int frequencia = 22050;
    Uint16 formato = AUDIO_S16SYS;
    int canal = 2; // 1 mono; 2 = stereo;
    int buffer = 4096;
    Mix_OpenAudio(frequencia, formato, canal, buffer);

    Mix_Chunk* sound_1;
    Mix_Chunk* sound_2;
    Mix_Chunk* sound_3;
    Mix_Chunk* sound_4;

    som_1 = Mix_LoadWAV("D:\\sound1.wav");
    som_2 = Mix_LoadWAV("D:\\sound2.wav");
    som_3 = Mix_LoadWAV("D:\\sound3.wav");
    som_4 = Mix_LoadWAV("D:\\sound4.wav");

    Mix_PlayChannel(-1, sound_1, 0);
    Mix_PlayChannel(1, sound_2, 0);
    Mix_PlayChannel(2, sound_3, 0);
    Mix_PlayChannel(3, sound_4, 0);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is the echo (echo echo) in the title intentional? Also you are loading the same sound 4 four times, wouldn't it be enough to load it once, and play it four times?

Comment: Thanks. Not intentional. It was a wrong....

Comment: I'm not playng same sound. 4 sounds are different

Answer (score 5):

Check in a loop whether the channel is still playing using [Mix_Playing()](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_38.html), and add a delay using [SDL_Delay()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Delay) to prevent the loop from consuming all available CPU time.

(In this example, I changed your first call to `Mix_PlayChannel()` from -1 to 1.)

```
Mix_PlayChannel(1, sound_1, 0);
while (Mix_Playing(1) != 0) {
    SDL_Delay(200); // wait 200 milliseconds
}

Mix_PlayChannel(2, sound_2, 0);
while (Mix_Playing(2) != 0) {
    SDL_Delay(200); // wait 200 milliseconds
}

// etc.
```

You should probably wrap that into a function instead so that you don't repeat what is basically the same code over and over again:

```
void PlayAndWait(int channel, Mix_Chunk* chunk, int loops)
{
    channel = Mix_PlayChannel(channel, chunk, loops);
    if (channel < 0) {
        return; // error
    }
    while (Mix_Playing(channel) != 0) {
        SDL_Delay(200);
    }
}

// ...

PlayAndWait(-1, sound_1, 0);
PlayAndWait(1, sound_2, 0);
PlayAndWait(2, sound_3, 0);
PlayAndWait(3, sound_3, 0);
```

Comment: almost works fine... setting delay in 0, even so, there are a small silence between sound 1 and 2... i need the sound 2 play imediatly after sound 1, whitout latency...

Comment: @mrsoliver I don't know if SDL_mixer can do gapless playback.